# Centos Ports for Updates, Repositories etc

Tags: centos, port

I want to use a Proxy-Server which is free to use from the network, my nodes are placed in. But this Proxy only allows the Port 80.

My question is, if somebody knows, which ports are used for the updates from the repositories etc. of a CentOS7 installation.

Thanks in advance.

most sincerely
Twinhand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard web ports: HTTP and HTTPS. From my experience all repositories publish via HTTP and most of them via HTTPS (but not all of them)